# Decent file manager with miller columns?

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager, dolphin, marlin

Is there a decent file manager with [Miller columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns)?

I found marlin and dolphin so far. I like marlin, but it's seems quite buggy. Dolphin I like not so much. It lets me choose between single and double click to open files, but if i choose double click, this also applies to folders in columns view. Are there alternatives?

EDIT: Columns view was removed from Dolphin altogether.