# How can I see a folder and a subfolder in the same window?

Tags: nautilus, pantheon

How can I navigate folders and subfolders at the same time?

Like "column view" in Mac OS X.

[image]

Edit 2: I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I couldn't install Marlin, so I installed "Pantheon File Manager" instead.

Comment: http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20081224191928555/FileManagers.html

Comment: But of those 14 only dolphin has miller columns as far as i see. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported as a bug in Dolphin? Miller columns should always use single click.

Comment: I hope you are aware of tabs in the file broswer. If not press Ctrl + t for a new tab in the same window.

Comment: I mean column view, and thank you for adding the image, i can't because i have less that 10 rep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decent file manager with miller columns?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114007/decent-file-manager-with-miller-columns)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes I got it.. It's **marlin file manager**

[image]

If you want to install execute following commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install marlin
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: +1. I think its Ctrl+1 for Files 3.10.

Comment: Yeah, the same but in column view not tree.

Comment: @Jobin: It's **ctrl** + **2** in nautilus installed in 12.04.. :P Actually there is a file manager which shows exactly the same way as OP wants.. But I'm not able to remember it..

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean, thank you, i will install marlin now.

Comment: That's lame because you have to add a repository, which is a security risk.

Comment: I use "Pantheon File Manager" now because I couldn't install Marlin in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 11):

This is one of the main reasons I always use List View:

[image]

It's not always ideal.

Some file managers have a multi-pane option. Nautilus used to but this was stripped back. There has been [a bit of a struggle to get it back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285588/is-there-a-way-to-restore-nautilus-split-screen-f3-feature) but I'm not sure how viable that is now.

I use Dolphin these days (I'm also a KDE user so that makes sense for me) which might be an option if you're doing this a lot. List view plus split screen FTW:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, i like list view, but it confuse me when i have lot files, so am looking for "column view", similar to multi-pane that you said.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Marlin](https://launchpad.net/~marlin-devs/+archive/marlin-daily), which is much less buggy than it was before, or [Pantheon Files](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily), which is forked from Marlin for the elementaryOS.

Installation instructions may be found on the following Q&A:

[How can I colour code my files like on a Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185454/how-can-i-colour-code-my-files-like-on-a-mac/185503#185503)

Comment: I just gave marlin another try, segfault after 15 seconds. I fear it still isn't ready for prime time.

Answer (score 4):

Your best choice is ranger, which is terminal based.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how to install ranger (and perhaps also how to use it)?

Comment: ranger is available from the Ubuntu repos since 11.10.

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus, the file browser in Ubuntu supports mutliple tabs. You can have multiple locations open in the same window, but in different tabs.

- To open a new tab in Nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
- To open a folder in a new tab, focus on the folder and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- To close a tab, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

Comment: Yes, thank you, but i mean "columnview" like this:
http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap4_9780321857880/elementLinks/04_25_columnview.jpg

Answer (score 2):

According to wikipedia, [Marlin does not have any download files registered with Launchpad as of November 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns#Use_in_file_browsers).

This was still true as of April 2019, and currently in 2020, so entering the following in the terminal will probably not work:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install marlin
```

...and most likely you will get an error like `Unable to locate package marlin`

### Instead try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

f.y.i. pantheon files is the file manager for Elementary OS, and is forked from Marlin:

[Thanks @jmunsch](https://askubuntu.com/a/396109/443059)

Comment: Thank you, that's why I left Ubuntu and now I'm using Elementary OS.

Comment: @IhabShoully how is it? it was sort of buggy last time i played around with it ~3 years ago. ...for what it's worth, I've sort of taken a liking to MX Linux lately.

Comment: Yes, it was buggy then but now it's stable.

Comment: Cool! i'll have to give it a second look...