# How can get Mac Os like column view in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, directory

[image]

Navigating the folders and sub folders in the same window
My question is quite similar to [How can I see a folder and a subfolder in the same window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442941/how-can-i-see-a-folder-and-a-subfolder-in-the-same-window) but It is not working for `ubuntu 16.04` is there any alternatives ?
That image is also from the same [URL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442941/how-can-i-see-a-folder-and-a-subfolder-in-the-same-window)
I love the present system of architecture of `Ubuntu` but I work with many folders opening and navigating taking me more time so I found this kinda feature in `mac` so ,is one having for ubuntu too?

After trying the @jadenPete answer it raised the following errors 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the PPA is intended for older releases. You can still use it though. Try using the following series of commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo sed 's/xenial/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-xenial.list
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-xenial.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-saucy.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install marlin
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it did not work .... I have added the out put file after trying your commands .

Comment: `sudo sed 's/xenial/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-xenial.list` and  `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-xenial.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/marlin-devs-marlin-daily-saucy.list` these two commands raised no such file or directory error

Comment: Try doing `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; sudo apt-get update`. If that doesn't work try `sudo apt-get update` one more time. This error happens to me sometimes.

Comment: no luck same errors repeating

Comment: ` Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
` this is the error

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get clean`?

Comment: It did not work. are you using it now ?