# How can I install Marlin file manager in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, filemanager

Since nautilus doesn't have a column view option I want to install marlin file manager which provides column view.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 installed machine. I tried several ways proposed on the web to install marlin. But none of these methods work for me.

I really want to install Marlin, not any similar application. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see a folder and a subfolder in the same window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442941/how-can-i-see-a-folder-and-a-subfolder-in-the-same-window)

Comment: @karel Nope. I know the marlin can solve the column view. But the problem is it can't install in the Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That's exactly why it's a duplicate, because **Marlin has been renamed to Pantheon file manager** and is currently being maintained under that name.

Answer (score 1):

As [explained by karel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098694/how-to-install-marlin-file-manager-in-ubuntu-16-04#comment1810150_1098694), Marlin has been renamed to Pantheon file manager.

This is how I solved the problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install pantheon-files
```

To launch Pantheon Files, type Files in the Ubuntu Launcher.